# What is the right way to use Espresso in android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to run an Espresso test for my android app, but there is a problem that has been troubling me. In MainActivity, some views' visibility depends on data loaded from net, but in MainActivityTest, I can't manipulate the process of loading data, so I don't know the real data and which view should show and which view should not show. As a result, I don't know how to continue my test. Anyone can tell me how to handle this situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) library.  It lets you mock http responses in your tests, like this:

```
     /**
     * Constructor for the test.  Set up the mock web server here, so that the base
     * URL for the application can be changed before the application loads
     */
    public MyActivityTest() {
        MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Set the base URL for the application
        MyApplication.sBaseUrl = server.url("/").toString();


        //Create a dispatcher to handle requests to the mock web server
        Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher() {

            @Override
            public MockResponse dispatch(RecordedRequest recordedRequest) throws InterruptedException {
            try {
                //When the activity requests the profile data, send it this
                if(recordedRequest.getPath().startsWith("/users/self")) {
                    String fileName = "profile_200.json";
                    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
                    String jsonString = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(in));
                    return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(jsonString);
                }
                //When the activity requests the image data, send it this
                if(recordedRequest.getPath().startsWith("/users/self/media/recent")) {
                    String fileName = "media_collection_model_test.json";
                    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
                    String jsonString = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(in));
                    return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(jsonString);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(404);
            }
        };
        server.setDispatcher(dispatcher);


    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.